# I can't open variable file name

Tags: c++, file, file-io

Is there any reason why `Dev C++` is not letting me do `file.open(file_name_variable)`? I don't understand why it's not letting me open anything but a hardcoded name like `file.open("abc.txt")` how do get around this? Don't use Dev C++?

here's basically what I have:

```
int open_file(string file_name){
    ifstream file;
    file.open(file_name);
    if (!file.is_open()){
        return 0;       
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a complete, minimal, compilable code snippet that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: And tell us what errors you get or how it "isn't letting you open the file".

Comment: @calccrypto: This is not compilable; please include a `main` function to demonstrate how you're using this.

Comment: theres not much to say about the main. im simply inputting a string called fname, which is inputted by the user.

Comment: It might indeed be a good idea not to use dev c++ by the way. It has not been actively worked on for more than 5 years now.

Comment: And is there any possibility you're giving it an invalid filename? Perhaps the path is relative to the wrong directory?

Comment: im checking for invalid file names in the next line. @BKevelham, whats a good ide for c++? i dont like ms visual studio express. i dont really use dev c++ either. i just use it to compile

Comment: Well, I would have recommended VS Express as a free option. Can't really recommend anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass it a c-string.  Use:

```
file.open( file_name.c_str() );
```

In C++11, this is no longer necessary.  A signature that takes `std::string` was added.

Answer (score 1):

`fstream::open` requires a `const char *` as first argument.

```
void open ( const char * filename,
        ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out );
```

It does not take a `std::string` (which is a shame by the way).
You need to convert your `std::string` to a `const char *`

```
file.open(file_name.c_str())
```

Answer (score 0):

Alexandre's right, I think. The signature of open is:

void open(const char *filename, ios_base::openmode mode);

You're trying to pass a std::string in as a const char *, but std::string doesn't have an operator const char * (for safety reasons). Instead, you have to use the c_str() method. The issue is not that the implicit conversion to const char * should be available, but that basic_ifstream should have an open overload that accepts a string -- to the best of my knowledge, this is being added in C++0x, but I don't have a reference for that offhand.